# Deleting the object that a pointer in a vector of pointers points to

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I have a vector of pointers that point to dynamically allocated Martian structs. My add function seems to work fine but I'm afraid of my delete function not doing a proper delete of the object and pointer. Could you guys look through the delete function and tell where i would fix the problem?

```
struct Martian
{
   string fname, lname, ssid;
   Martian(string fname, string lname, string ssid) : fname(fname), lname(lname), ssid(ssid){}
};

class martianDatabase
{
   public:
      vector<Martian*> database;
      martianDatabase();
      void deleteMartian(string deletedID);
      void addMartian(int &i, string f, string l, string id);
      int iterator = 0, size = 0;
};

void martianDatabase::addMartian(int& i, string f, string l, string id)
{
   this->database.push_back(new Martian(f, l, id));
   i++;
}

void martianDatabase::deleteMartian(string deleteID)
{
   int i = 0;
   while (i < size +1)
   {
      if (this->database[i]->ssid == deleteID){
         delete this->database[i];
         size--;
         break;
      }
      else ++i;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `size` from? and by `size--` you lost the element which is at then end of the vector and not the element you are trying to delete. And not lost actually but ignored.

Comment: You are not removing the item from the vector anywhere, so next time you try to delete you may attempt to read from memory that has been freed.

Comment: This is an open ended question. Generic code reviews to point out what's wrong in your code is off topic.

Comment: @FirstStep oops forgot to add that

Comment: @TheDark the delete function isn't deleting anything? would  
this->database.erase(this->database.begin()+i);
   delete an element of the vector?

Comment: Yes, that would remove the item from the vector. You still need the 'delete' that you already have.

Comment: @TheDark so with that the i-th element of my vector would be empty or would i have to set it to null?

Comment: The i-th element would be removed, so the (i+1)-th element would now be the i-th element. Your vector would be shorter by one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This deletes all `Martian` objects with matching `ssid` values.

```
void martianDatabase::deleteMartian( string deleteID )
{
    auto martianIterator = database.begin();

    while( martianIterator != database.end() )
    {
        if( (*martianIterator)->ssid == deleteID )
        {
            delete *martianIterator;
            martianIterator = database.erase( martianIterator );
        }
        else
        {
            ++martianIterator;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i directly p-lug that in, i get the error     Member reference base type 'Martian *' is not a structure or union    on the   if( *(martianIterator)->ssid == deleteID ) line

Comment: Oops, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

By calling delete on a pointer you will free the memory space used by the pointed object (in fact the memory will not be freed, but let say it will be reusable).

The problem you will encounter with your program is that you delete your entry, then reduce your vector's size, but the pointer is not removed and not set to nullptr, which means you will have issues when trying to dereference it (your code will only work if you delete the last element).

Also, you could (should ?) use the new smart pointers introduced by c++11, in your case you could replace your raw pointers with std::shared_ptr.

For more information:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr